# where does castle windsor fit in?

Tags: nhibernate, domain-driven-design, castle-windsor, castle

I'm trying to draw up a Technical Architecture Diagram for a Distributed Domain Driven Design based system using nHibernate, Castle Windsor, WCF, and ASP .NET

I used the typical layers i.e. Infrastructure, Interfaces, Application and Domain layers

Is my understanding correct to group nHibernate, Castle Windsor, WCF as part of Infrastructure layer as per DDD?

Please advise.

Comment: You seem to be stating some of your architecture decisions, but you are not really asking a question ?

Comment: @driis can you please comment now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your correct in your statement that nHibernate, Castle Windsor, WCF should be in a infrastructure layer.

In reality their usage differs. 
WCF are often placed in a separate assembly/project and can therefore be seen as infralayer since we move it out from presentation, service and domain assemlies/projects.

Nhibernate are often only referenced in data/infra assembly, but some Nhibernate patters also uses Global.asax or a CustomHttpModule to configure Nhibernate session for each web request. This can be handy but also require extra references.

Castle on the otherhand can be useful in all layers. A static wrapper can easily be done to remove many Castle references or take a look at the Microsoft Practices team's Common Service Locator. It can also help in decouple dependencies so a specific DI tool.